# Rails 4 ActiveModel won't update_columns when tested with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

In a normal test using human and browser, everything is work as expected. However, when I use rspec, I can see that I have:

```
D, [2014-08-16T13:48:09.510013 #19418] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "system_flights_cacheds" SET "client_stuff" = '{"captcha":"656556"}' WHERE "system_flights_cacheds"."guid" = '5647046e-4194-498e-a0d7-512614b147d8'
```

But I cannot believe that actually my database record is not updated. Previously I used .save, but with no success in fact it creates SAVEPOINT.

My code in trouble is basically an API endpoint:

```
cache = System::Flights::Cached.search_cache options

# update database, when the captcha is present. this way, the worker
# when updating the database can see the changes and act accordingly!
if cache && params[:captcha]
  # remember, anyone can (basically) see the captcha. thus,
  # this is a bit paranoid, only allow captcha update
  # if the user is same! in the json, if not forgotten,
  # captcha is only displayed when the user_id is equal
  server_stuff = cache.server_stuff.with_indifferent_access
  if server_stuff[:user_id] == current_user.id
    cache.time_renewed = 10
    cache.client_stuff_will_change!
    cache.client_stuff ||= {}
    cache.client_stuff[:captcha] = params[:captcha]
    # cache.save!
    cache.update_columns(client_stuff: cache.client_stuff)
  end
else
  # only spawn worker if there is no captcha parameter passed
  spawn_search_worker({user_id: current_user.id, options: options})
end
```

The client can reach this anytime and it will span worker. When a new record is already in database but is_processed is false, the worker will quit. Thus, calling this multiple times will be ok as also be a means to check status if the work is done or not.

The worker will wait the client to enter for a captcha. So, we have class like WaitableLogin, that do basically:

```
  max_repeat = 3 # 14

  # annul flag, if set to true, the data will not get persisted.
  annul = false

  while max_repeat > 0
    # interval of 5 secs that worker can check the database
    sleep 5

    max_repeat -= 1

    # break if captcha already entered by client
    # seek from the database if the client has posted
    # the captcha text
    cache = System::Flights::Cached.search_cache options
    client_stuff = nil
    client_stuff = cache.client_stuff.with_indifferent_access if cache && cache.client_stuff

    if client_stuff && client_stuff[:captcha]
      captcha_text = client_stuff[:captcha]
      airline.fill_captcha(captcha_text).finalize_login

      puts "SOMEHOW I AM HERE: #{captcha_text}"

      # remove all server's stuff
      cache.server_stuff_will_change!
      cache.server_stuff.clear
      cache.save!

      annul = airline.in_login_page?
    end
  end
```

So, WaitableLogin will check if the client_stuff is updated. If it is, then we know that client has submitted the captcha (through the Endpoint, the worker will check if captcha is a param and will update the database if there's captcha field).

The control then transferred back to the Worker. You can see that there's a lot of code that use cache at many parts of the codes across files, cache is just variable name nothing to do with its semantic meaning in Rails or whatever.

When I run normally on browser, I don't see any problem. In fact, no SAVEPOINT even if I use .save. I thought, it is creating some bug somewhere with that SAVEPOINT so I decided to try using .update_columns. But, again, with no success.

This is what the test looks like
    before(:each) do
        System::Flights::Cached.delete_all
      end

```
  describe "requests" do
    it "should process 2a1c1i" do
      cached = nil
      post("/api/v1/x.json", {
          access_token: CommonFlightData::ACCESS_TOKEN,
          business_token: CommonFlightData::BUSINESS_TOKEN,
          captcha: ""
      }.merge!(CommonFlightData.oneway_1a(from: "8-9-2014")))

      puts "enter the captcha: "
      captcha = STDIN.gets.chomp
      puts "Entered: #{captcha}"

      post("/api/v1/x.json", {
          access_token: CommonFlightData::ACCESS_TOKEN,
          business_token: CommonFlightData::BUSINESS_TOKEN,
          captcha: captcha
      }.merge!(CommonFlightData.oneway_1a(from: "8-9-2014")))
      sleep 10
```

SO what am I missing at, I tired. No error raised. When I check .inspect after update_columns, it seems all is updated. But, when you see at the database, nothing is updated.

EDIT: I put lock_version so that I have optimistic locking (by default, I think). And turn out, as expected, it was set to 2.

EDIT 2: If I command an edit from a rails console at the time when the code asking for captcha, IT UPDATES the data. SO, why the RSpec spec that run the api endpoint to submit a captcha won't update the row. All real-life no spec-in-origin code is finely executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437760/where-does-rails-store-data-created-by-saving-activerecord-objects-during-tests might be relevant

Comment: nope. but thanks. the problem is not fixtures I believe. because it is under one "it" test.

Comment: this is the weirdest things ever happen in my career

Comment: The key point in that question isn't the use or not of fixtures, but that tests happen in transactions. How are you checking the database for changes ?

Comment: I don't use fixtures. It supposed to test the API from POST call and "programatic" call. The programatic call just call the API module directly, while POST call will call the controller's code. The problem is only in testing, not in real use. Does it have anything to do with Optimistic locking? (2) I check manually from pgAdmin and RubyMine database feature. It itself contradicts with .inspect I used in the source that print the cache.

Comment: Tests run inside a transaction. The default isolation levels for transaction mean changes aren't visible to other connections.

Comment: Even if the code that changes the database located far from the spec file? ...so, what should I do?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem you're having is (other than being able to see data set by tests in pgadmin). Is it that the worker doesn't see the changes? How is the worker executed?

Comment: Not only the worker don't see the changes, the PgAdmin and RubyMine database also don't see it. Only local code can print client_stuff and it contains :cache, other (outsider code) cannot. FYI, I use Redis Sidekiq and use Semaphore to lock the worker. I terribly confused.

Comment: Are you using any of the sidekiq testing modes (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing) or do you actually have a sidekiq instance running? If the latter you'll probably have to disable transactions for those specs.

Comment: nope. I did not intend to test Sidekiq per se. I try to emulate use request but automated using rspec spec.

Comment: If by nope you mean that you're running a normal sidekiq instance then you almost certainly want to be using the "inline" testing mode

Comment: What's that "inline" testing mode is? I don't really think it's matter, because my usual call of API method works, which itself is also using Sidekiq. Anyway, what's that?

Comment: Inline testing node means that the work passed to sidekiq is done straightaway instead of being queued. This means that the worker code is executed in the same thread, so same database connection so you don't have the transaction isolation level problems you're having.

Comment: if that really matters? cus I can update the database field even in a different process altogether.